# Display Label given key for select list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck, drupal-fields

Given the following select list for the "field_priority" field, how can I display the label, given the key (e.g. 0, 1, 3)?

```
0|Low
1|Medium
2|High
3|Urgent
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it nice and quickly using [`field_info_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7):

```
$key = 0; // Or whatever
$field = field_info_field('field_priority');
$label = $field['settings']['allowed_values'][$key];
```

There's a whole host of field functions in [field.info.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/7), they're very handy.

Comment: are form fields also fields so that you could use this function for a selected option in the validate/submit handler?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `list_allowed_values()` instead of searching the array yourself:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_priority');
$options = list_allowed_values($field);
$label = $values[$key];
```

Or in short:

```
$label = list_allowed_values(field_info_field('field_priority'))[$key];
```